# How to create new Kotlin project by CLI?

Tags: kotlin, command-line-interface

In `dotnet` I have a bunch of templates in `dotnet new <template>`, but how to do the same thing in `kotlin`?

Something like this

```
kotlin new kotlinNativeConsole
```

Which will create new native kotlin console application like single `print("hello world!")`

P.S(I know about intellij idea and it's templates, but I refuse to use because it simply not works on my machine and I always prefer command line)

Comment: `mkdir project ; cd project ; touch hello.kt`? A hello world application is going to be one file anyway. Do you need a command line tool to generate that one file for you?

Comment: Kotlin works with the [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/what_is_gradle.html) build system, so are you looking for `gradle init`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/what_is_gradle.html) has templates like that. You can download it [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html). This is in fact what IntelliJ IDEA uses to build Kotlin Native projects. I'll show you how you can use it on the command line, since you don't seem to like IntelliJ. To generate a new project, do

```
gradle init
```

And it will produce a new project wizard like this:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

Select type of project to generate:
  1: basic
  2: application
  3: library
  4: Gradle plugin
Enter selection (default: basic) [1..4] 2

Select implementation language:
  1: C++
  2: Groovy
  3: Java
  4: Kotlin
  5: Scala
  6: Swift
Enter selection (default: Java) [1..6] 4

Split functionality across multiple subprojects?:
  1: no - only one application project
  2: yes - application and library projects
Enter selection (default: no - only one application project) [1..2] 1

Select build script DSL:
  1: Groovy
  2: Kotlin
Enter selection (default: Kotlin) [1..2] 2

Project name (default: MyProject): 
Source package (default: MyProject): myproject

> Task :init
Get more help with your project: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/samples/sample_building_kotlin_applications.html

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 47s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

After selecting those options, you get a project structure like this:

[image]

App.kt looks like this:

```
/*
 * This Kotlin source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package myproject

class App {
    val greeting: String
        get() {
            return "Hello World!"
        }
}

fun main() {
    println(App().greeting)
}
```

Note that this project template is a Kotlin/JVM project. For a Kotlin/Native project, you should follow the instructions [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-gradle.html#create-project-files). To summarise, you should edit the build.gradle.kts file to include the Kotlin/Native plugin, then create a `src/nativeMain/kotlin` folder to put your `main` function there.

Comment: For me, it's not that I don't like IntelliJ IDEA. But it's not always available, so being able to do everything on the command line is very useful.