# Kotlin: Errors on virtual studio code when kotlin coding

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use vscode to coding with kotlin. After installing *kotlin language* and *code runner* extensions on **vscode** and install **kotlin** by snap on my **mxlinux**:

```
alt@mx:~
$ snap list
Name    Version    Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes
core    16-2.51.4  11606  latest/stable  canonical✓  core
kotlin  1.5.30     61     latest/stable  jetbrains✓  classic
alt@mx:~

alt@mx:~
$ snap version
snap    2.51.4
snapd   2.51.4
series  16
debian  10
kernel  4.19.0-17-amd64
alt@mx:~
```

I wrote this code on vscode:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var string = "Hello Students!"
    val age: Int = 23
    println(string)
    println(age)
}
```

and run I got result and error:

```
[Running] cd "/mnt/Project/Android/Practise/Kotlin/Practices/tuto1/" && kotlinc HelloWorld.kt -include-runtime -d HelloWorld.jar && java -jar HelloWorld.jar
HelloWorld.kt:1:10: warning: parameter 'args' is never used
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
         ^
Hello Students!
23

[Done] exited with code=0 in 12.147 seconds
```

And In Ide there are a lots of error:
[image]

Comment: "parameter 'args' is never used" is not an error. It clearly says that it is a _warning_.

Comment: Also, which extension did you install? Can you post the links? I used [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fwcd.kotlin) and it works. The error that you got in VS code suggests that you need to specify the `-include-runtime` option in somewhere.

Comment: I installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fwcd.kotlin and https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mathiasfrohlich.Kotlin extension

Comment: Have I add `-include-runtime` somewhere? where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and run I got result and error

That is not an error. As it clearly says, it is a *warning*. Warnings don't stop your code from compiling and running. If you don't want the warning, you can pass the `-nowarn` compiler option to `kotlinc`. If you do want the warning to stop your code from compiling, pass `-Werror` instead. [See list of compiler options here.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compiler-reference.html#)

> And In Ide there are a lots of error

From the description of the [Kotlin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fwcd.kotlin) VSCode extension, you are supposed to open a Gradle/Maven project (see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69081703/5133585) for how to create one), and "support for Kotlin source files with a standalone compiler is experimental". I've also found this [issue](https://github.com/fwcd/vscode-kotlin/issues/56) that points out that even if you don't use Gradle or Maven, you still have to open a *folder*.

So rather than opening the file like this:

```
$ code MyProject/HelloWorld.kt
```

You should open it like this:

```
$ code MyProject
```

In other words, open the folder that contains the kotlin file.

Comment: Yep, I need gradle